# signalR How to call server method from .net client

Tags: c#, signalr, invoke

I want to pass arguments from .net client(Xamarin Android) to hub server.
I call server method in serverHub by method "invoke"

HubServer code:

```
public class ConversationHub : Hub{

public void SendChatMessage(int conversationId, int messageId, string messageText, bool isChat, LinkViewModel link)
// logic in the method
    }
}
```

My entity

```
public class Message: Entity<int>
{
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ImgUrl { get; set; }
        public virtual DetailMessage DetailMessage {get; set;}
}
```

My object(model) which I want to pass from .Net client to serverHub by calling method "invoke".

```
public class  LinkViewModel
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ImgUrl { get; set; }

        public LinkViewModel(){}
        public LinkViewModel(Message message){
           Url = message.Url;
           Title = message.Title;
           Description  = message.Description;
           ImgUrl = message.ImgUrl;
```

}
    }

Client .Net code(Xamarin Android):

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection(hubUrl);
 var chatHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ConversationHub");
 chatHubProxy.Invoke("SendChatMessage", 3, 0, "Hello world!", false, myObj); // I want to call method from HubConversation
```

but it -

```
chatHubProxy.Invoke("SendChatMessage", 3, 0, "Hello world!", false, myObj);
```

doesn't work, because signalR doesn't want to pass complex object. If I remove parameter "myObj" from method on client and server. Method Invoke will be work successfully . 
How to call method "invoke" with object parameter?

Also I use this serverHub method(sendChatmessage) from UI in js:

```
myHub.conversationHub.server.sendChatMessage(data.conversationId, data.messageId, data.messageText, data.isChat, JSON.parse(link));
```

link represents LinkViewModel in UI. Calling method sendChatMessage in JS works without any problem, but with problem from .Net client. How to resolve this.

**Updated:**

Also I tried to convert myObj to Json(but it doesn't work):

```
string jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj);// serialization myObj
var hubConnection = new HubConnection(hubUrl);
var chatHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ConversationHub");
     chatHubProxy.Invoke("SendChatMessage", 3, 0, "Hello world!", false, jsonObject); //pass object as json string, but it doesn't work
```

**Solution:**

I resolve this problem. **When I call method "invoke" from .Net client, first parameters should be objects then primitives**, only in this order(for example in my case):

```
chatHubProxy.Invoke("SendChatMessage", myObj, 3, 0, "Hello world!", false);//firstly objects
```

And after this I changed corresponding order parameters in UI and Hub methods. And all code fine works-)

Comment: It should work if LinkViewModel is not a derived type.

Comment: It's strange. Do you receive any error oder the message just doesn't come? SignalR can send complex object. For example, this post has demo for sending complex object http://hintdesk.com/c-introduction-to-signalr/

Comment: if your client/server have reference to `LinkViewModel` you can pass from the `linkViewModel` as object or the other way to send as `json` string and `deserialize` it

Comment: @MaDeRkAn LinkViewModel is not a derived type. I also added entity which used by model LinkViewModel. Maybe it helps to understand more better my code.

Comment: @LexLi  it doesn't help me. I've updated my post with JSON code.Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @Eldho I tried do this, and I've updated my post with json code, but it doesn't help me. ANd yeah, both client and server have reference to LinkViewModel.

Comment: @LexLi If I understand you right, my own  - it is my .net client, I tried this, but it doesn't work. If you meant about serverHub  like this -  public void SendChatMessage(int conversationId, int messageId, string messageText, bool isChat, string jsonObject) i will try to do this, but I dont understand why serverHub can automatically parse string from UI(javascript), but cannot parse automatically same json string from .net client?

Comment: Normaly signalr net client uses JsonSerializer and converts your object to json internally. But may be Xamarin Android doesn't have this internally. Can you serilaize before send.

Comment: @MaDeRkAn I serialize before send, but it doesn't work. It is strangely because when passing json object from ui it automatically deserialize json, but when I send same json object from .net Xamarin by method invoke, it doesn't work. Perhaps the problem hides on the specific work method "invoke".

Comment: @IgorLevkivskiy Sorry, i had tried in wpf client and server and it works well for me.

Comment: Thanks all for helping I resolve this, Problem was in sequence parameters in method "invoke", First elements should be objects.